# How to create proxy repository in nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I was reading couple of blogs to work with Nexus. I was trying to create the proxy repository, for the artifacts of Spring Boot. And I am also not finding good examples of proxy the url using Nexus.

Comment: What about reading the original documentation https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-new-repo.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I had gone through the book, but i am not convinced with the explanation. As it just says how to create the proxy, but doesnt explain with the example.

Comment: By default maven central is configured as a proxy...What do you miss?

Comment: I just need one external example, to create the proxy

Answer (score 1):

A Proxy repo in Nexus is the same as a Remote repo in Artifactory. It's simply a bridge to the existing remote repositories such as Maven Central, NuGet Gallary, etc. The instruction to set up such a Proxy repo can be found here:
https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-new-repo.html

Below is an example on how to setup the proxy repo in Nexus Pro 2.11 for the NuGet Gallary.

[image]